# Java - Managing Size of Thread Pool (Increasing mostly)

Tags: java, threadpool

I'm trying to use thread pool in Java. But the number of threads is unknown, so I'm trying to find a solution. Then two questions occured:

1. I'm looking for increasing size of thread pool for some time, but I couldn't come up with something yet. Any suggestions for that? Some say `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` should work but in definition of the method it says it's for short-time threads.
2. What if I set the size of the thread pool as a big number like 50 or 100? Does it work fine?

Comment: Have you tried monitoring your JVM using JConsole?

Comment: @AmitBhargava No I didn't try, I'm just doing some research now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can use Executors.newCachedThreadPool for more long-lived tasks also, but the thing is that if you have long running tasks, and they're added constantly and more frequently than existing tasks are being completed, the amount of threads will spin out of control. In such case it might be a better idea to use a (larger) fixed-size thread pool and let the further tasks wait in queue for a free thread.
2. This will only mean you'll (probably) have lots of alive threads that are sleeping (idle) most of the time. Basically the things to consider are

   - How many threads can your system handle (ie. how many threads can be created in total, in Windows-machines this can be less than 1000, in Linuces you can get tens of thousands of thread and even more with some tweaking of the system configuration)
   - Each thread consumes at least the stack size of a single thread in terms of memory (in Linux, this can be something like 1-8MB per thread by default, again it can be tweaked from ulimits and the JVM's `-Xss` -parameter)
   - At least with NPTL, there should minimal or almost zero context-switching penalty for sleeping threads, so excess threads aren't "heavy" in terms of cpu usage

That being said, it'd probably be best to use the [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)'s constructors directly to get the kind of pooling you want.

Comment: In second solution, do I have to fill the pool at start? Because in most cases the number of working thread will be under the maximum size.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "filling" the pool. ThreadPoolExecutor has the method prestartAllCoreThreads(), which starts "corePoolSize" amount of threads. Otherwise the pool will start a new thread based on the conditions documented in the ThreadPoolExecutors' JavaDoc (link in the answer).

Comment: For example, I set the size as 50, do I have to add 50 threads to pool or does it work fine with, let's say, 10 threads? I wondered this after you had said there would be lots of alive but idle threads. Probably it will work but I just want to be sure :)

Comment: A fixed size thread pool will create a new thread every time you submit a task to it, until it has created the given number of threads. After that, it will reuse the existing threads and queue any tasks for which there is no thread available immediately. I think we're speaking of the same thing, but using different terms, you do not submit threads (java.lang.Thread) to the pool, but Runnables (java.lang.Runnable -implementations) or Callables (java.util.concurrent.Callable -implementations), and the pool will take care of creating the threads for you as needed.

Answer (score 2):

`Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` allows you to create thread on demands. I think you can start by using this - I cannot see where it's stated that it's for short-time threads, but I bet the reason is since you are re-using available threads, having short threads allows you to keep the number of simultaneous active threads quite low.

Unless you've got too many threads running (you can check it using JVisualVM or JConsole), I would suggest sticking with that solution - specially because number of expected threads is undefined. Analyze then the VM and tune your pool accordingly.

For question 2 - were you referring to using something like `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int)`? If yes, remember that going aobve the number of threads you defined when you've created the `ThreadPool` will make threads wait - instead of `newCachedThreadPool` in which new threads are dynamically created.

Comment: I know that threads will wait, thanks. I'm wondering if a problem occurs when I use the second solution.

Comment: @mtyurt Yes, you can cause problems by using your second solution (a large thread pool of dozens or hundreds). If those threads in the pool are CPU-bound (busy doing calculations as opposed to waiting for storage I/O or network activity) then the cost of [context-switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) can become burdensome and counter-productive. By counter-productive I mean overall performance goes *down* as less and less real productive work gets done. This Answer correctly points out that your tasks can be queued to wait. Waiting means no work, no context-switching.